# Loading a Single Series from a Pickled DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: pandas

After saving a Pandas DataFrame with `df.to_pickle(file_name)`, it can be loaded with `df = pd.read_pickle(file_name)`. But sometimes, you may only want to load the data for one Series at a particular time, and loading the entire DataFrame is inefficient. Is there a way to load just a single Series from a pickled DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because pickle files are serialized and reading a single column of a serialized file is not possible. You can read a single column of other file types (i.e. h5, csv, etc.) but not a serialized file.